# problems with node Serialport write

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to send commands from a node server to an arduino mega board and back. It works fine as long I only call `SERIALPORT.write` only once in 1000ms, but If I try it faster, I don't get back any the control message.

node.js:

```
 if (SERIALPORT) {

        SERIALPORT.on("open", function () {
            SERIALPORT.on('data', function(data) {
                for (let c of data) {
                     console.log(c.toString());
                 }
            });

          });


        function repeat_function() {

            command = [1];

            SERIALPORT.write(command, function(err) {
                if (!err) { 
                    console.log('message writtn ' + command); 
                }
            });
            setTimeout(repeat_function, 1000);
        }
        repeat_function();
    }
```

arduino code:

```
void loop()
{   
   if (Serial.available()) {
      Serial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

If I try `setTimeout(myFunc, 500);` then I don't get back the serial data.

settings node.js:

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort(CONFIG.serial_port, {
                baudrat: 9600,
                dataBits: 8,
                parity: 'none',
                stopBits: 1,
                flowControl: false
            });
```

settings arduino:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
  }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with other higher baud rate (Ex: 57600 ).Increasing baud rate will help send and receive data faster.